# How to close python instance in dask debug

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am using dask client in local. The problem is when the task is finished I still have in memory a lot of python instance even if I use local scheduler. This is what I am doing:

```
x.compute(get=dask.get)
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()  # Starts local cluster
x.compute()
```

If I run this several time I will end up with several python.exe in my processes (on windows). Any way to prevent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can close a client with the `client.close()` method.

You can also use a context manager

```
with Client() as client:
    x.compute()
```

Comment: Thank you. There is no close method in client or I missed it. I am using dask 0.14.3.
It is working perfectly with the context manager.